# watchOS2 and iOS8 dilemma

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, watchos-2

I have an app, which is targeted primarily at **iOS8** users.
I'm thinking about porting it to AppleWatch, but i've faced the issue.

My first thought was using **watchOS2** for that purpose because of its wider possibilities and my key target audience, who have AppleWatch have already upgraded to **iOS9** and **watchOS2**.

So my question is - Would it be possible for me to create and successfully deploy the app to the AppStore with **iOS8** as an app bundle target and **watchOS2** as an Watch app bundle target? Will it create any conflicts for the end user?

Thank you.

Comment: Remember that all devices capable of running iOS 8 can run iOS 9. I cannot think of a reason not to simply up the version. iOS 9 adoption is really high.

Comment: It's 55% in the US among all of the devices (according to today's stats). Less than 2/3. @Schemetrical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing something similar. The only implication of what you are asking is that the Watch app will only be available to those users running iOS9 on their paired devices (as this is needed to upgrade the Watch to WatchOS2). In other words your app will then be available to three platforms: iOS8 devices, iOS9 devices, and Watches paired with iOS9 devices. Hope this helps?